# An identity in Hirzebruch's book

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry, power-series

Below is an identity in a proof on p15 of Topological Methods in Algebraic Geometry (Second, Corrected Printing of the Third Edition) by F.Hirzebruch.

> Let $\gamma_{1},\cdots,\gamma_{n},x,y$ be $n+2$ indeterminates and $Q(y,x)=\frac{x(y+1)}{1-e^{-x(y+1)}}$, then
> $$\varkappa_{n}\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(1+ye^{-(1+y)\gamma_{i}})}{1+y}\cdot \frac{(1+y)\gamma_{i}}{1-e^{-(1+y)\gamma_{i}}}\right]=\varkappa_{n}\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}Q(y;
> \gamma_{i})\right]$$ where $\varkappa_{n}[\cdot]$ denotes the sum of all homogeneous terms of degree $n$ in the $\gamma_{i}$ which occur in $[\cdot]$.

I have no idea how this equality is obtained.

Erratum:$Q(y,x)=\frac{x(y+1)}{1-e^{-x(y+1)}}-yx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed one term in your $Q(y; x)$. It should read
$$
Q(y; x)=\frac{x(y+1)}{1-e^{-x(y+1)}} - yx.
$$
The key is to just common denominator to get
$$
Q(y; x)= \frac{x(y+1)-yx(1-e^{-x(y+1)})}{1-e^{-x(y+1)}}=\frac{x(1+ye^{-x(y+1)})}{1-e^{-x(y+1)}}.
$$
Now this looks exactly like your term in the product with $x$ replaced by $\gamma_i$, after you cancel the two free $(1+y)$ factors.